# Generator function, predicate, Operation and many more in c++ STL?

Tags: c++, c++11

**std::remove_if**

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
  ForwardIterator remove_if (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, UnaryPredicate pred);
```

My teacher spent long hours in teaching *predicate* in the `std::remove_if` algorithm, so far I understand that *predicate* can be a function or function pointer that return `bool` or a function object having a `bool operator()` overload. However, when I learn more and more about STL library, I feel that predicate is a just one out of may kind of "operation" that can be passed to an algorithm. Just list a few more examples:

**std::generate**

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class Generator>
  void generate (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Generator gen);
```

**std::sort**

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void sort (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
```

**std::transform**

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperation>
  OutputIterator transform (InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
                            OutputIterator result, UnaryOperation op);
```

So here we see generator function, compare function, unaryoperation, etc. I believe there are many more. These function of serve different purpose (different return type) by taking in different type and number of input arguments. However, they all appear under different algorithm in the STL, and sometimes I find it confusing and write function incorrectly. Can someone point to me a collection of all the types of functions used by STL for my easier reference?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req ? Though sometimes a requirement is not explicitly named, e.g. `Generator`'s requirements are only given for `std::generate` without naming them: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate

Comment: Also note that you can also pass lambdas to these algorithms instead of function pointers or explicit function objects. Using lambdas is probably the most common use if the function is not too complex.

Comment: The old [SGI docs](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/functors.html) are also a good read, although obviously not now canonical. An exhaustive list (which may anyway not exist) is probably less helpful than understanding the semantics expected from each type of callable.